# how to install ubuntu from a flash drive?

Tags: usb, system-installation, flash

I asked this in a less than clear way before. Sorry about that. I have read around a bit but nothing seems clear to me or stands out as a how to do this.

So I am looking for a how to. this how to would descrie the tools needed, and the steps to accomplish making an ubuntu install USB. (Not a run Ubuntu from USB)

Currently I have various sized flash drives no less than 8 gigs. I am running win7-ult. I want to make a completely seperate Ubuntu install from this win7 system and drive. To to this I would like to use a USB installer instead of an optical drive and disc. (For future ease of install and because I am sure that it is a faster process than my ***sometimes*** recognized at start up, optical drive.

I have read one reply to someone's post to use unetcootin. That is as far as it goes. i am doing this to a new unused unwritten SSD. So I simply don't want to waste my first write to the disc screwing things up.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried some video tutorials like [this one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NxTqR4Y2vrk).

Comment: Not sure what the video is about I only speak English

Comment: I don't understand video too. Just follow the clicks :D

Answer (score 0):

Try [Yumi](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/yumi-multiboot-usb-creator/). This (free for personal use) utility allows you to place multiple installations on a single thumb drive. With it, you can create a thumb drive which lets you choose between a mix of several windows versions and linux versions for installation.

Simply start the software, download and select an appropriate version of Ubuntu (or any other O/S for that matter) and select the hard drive you wish to install it on. You can even add new/other O/S's to the same thumb drive later.

Comment: I don't want to install on the thumb drive.  I want to install from the thumb drive.  

I'm trying to be as clear in my request as possible.  I DON'T want to install to the Thumbdrive. I want install from a Thumbdrive to a ssd that is blank.                                               In other words the flash drive is not an operational till it is intended to replace the install cd.                                    Am I completely misunderstanding something or am I not explaining well enough.

Comment: Also who do I have to send a message to,  to make the enter key stop posting on comments. Enter is supposed to function to start a new paragraph.  The button below serves to submit the post. Makes this really difficult to do from a phone.

Comment: Okay is this yumi instal being done from windows?    ( I swear I am not trying to troll)                                                             bear with me. Just want to make sure that what you are telling me does what I am asking. Because what you are saying is install ubuntu using yumi while in windows. What I am asking to do is create a usb. This usb would act the same way a legit windows instal disc would. Only not be windows. It would be a instal USB. Not installed to usb or installed from windows, but a boot install from USB. (continued into the next comment.)

Comment: Not running on the USB just the installer ISO on the USB that will install ubunto to a blank disc from the USB at boot... Not windows boot. 

think of this as a system without windows preloaded. It is a raw computer with no windows I want a USB ubunto installer that will function at ami boot to install linux to the SSD available.

Answer (score 0):

I understood your question, my explanation wasn't clear enough. Yumi lets you place multiple extracted iso's on a thumb drive so you can use that thumb drive to install any of those. I've edited my previous answer;

"select the thumb drive you wish to install it on."

should have been:

"select the hard drive you wish to install it on."

Sorry for the mishap!

Answer (score 0):

So, i tried many things. I recommend you to use UNetBootin. It is so easy. Just select your .*iso and USB drive ,then click OK. My laptop doesn't boot from CD/DVD, so i used that.

This worked for me...